# New socket messed up by slashes?

Tags: java, sockets, slash

I have a java program that is trying to make an HTTP request over a socket. For some reason slashes in the string are messing it up.

I have a try/catch and it gets caught as soon as the socket is created with a string that has a slash.

```
        Socket socket = new Socket("www.google.ca", port);
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 54
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2016 06:05:43 GMT
Connection: close

<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>
```

Now with a slash

```
        Socket socket = new Socket("www.google.ca/", port);
```

Gets caught.

My request.

```
            outputStream.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
            outputStream.println("");
            outputStream.flush();
```

I'm trying to access a specific site with the hostname and path which has slashes.  What is happening?

Comment: Exception comes from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Because `www.google.ca/` is not a valid hostname. The path of the url should be located in the `GET` part. Read about HTTP protocol. If you want to connect to `http://host/path` you should open a TCP socket to `host` then use `GET /path`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` happens because of wrong request path. It is hard to find the reason without knowing your code.

The second error happens like Andy Turner already said, because the host name is wrong. [InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) can not resolve the host names with slashes.

This example works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("google.com"), 80);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    pw.println("GET /about/ HTTP/1.1"); // here comes the path
    pw.println("f-Modified-Since: Wed, 1 Oct 2017 07:00:00 GMT");
    pw.println("");
    pw.flush();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

You just have to set the path in this line:

```
pw.println("GET /about HTTP/1.1");
```

Comment: Okay makes sense.  Well for the assignment I'm working on I'm sure my professor will have his pages enabled for such.  

So.  Can anyone point me in the direction of how to send a proper HTTP request, WITHOUT using URL Connection, with updating the header I assume?

Comment: Bonus points... a conditional get request?  Say on the 'Last modified' time.

Comment: `Last Modified` comes from response header.

Comment: Check.  Thanks! That will do.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically than `IOException`, you are getting an `UnknownHostException` (a subclass of `IOException`), because host names can't contain a slash.

You should print/log the exception's stack trace in the catch block; this problem would then be a lot more apparent.

Comment: Sorry, how do I make a proper http request then? To the path I'm looking for.  Finding information on this without using URL Connection is impossible.

Comment: No idea, as you're not showing how you build the http request. I'm simply answering why it fails immediately with a slash.

Comment: What I have there for outputStream.println's is all I have.  I'm passed a regular URL like www.google.com/docs/about.html as a parameter.